# Filling a JPanel with JRadioButtons using HashMap

Tags: java, swing, hashmap

I've been stuck on trying to figure out how to make a popout window that is dynamically created based on the array's content and i'm almost certain that i'm missing something vital that might help me solve and fully understand this issue.

**What exactly am i trying to do?**

I have a program which loops through certain directory, collects all the folder names and stores it in an `ArrayList`. Problem arises when i try to dynamically create a window using that `ArrayList`. I'm not sure how exactly to tackle this.

**What's my current through process**

I have 3 classes. View, Model and Control class. Array with folders is stored in the model class. I retrieve it through control class. I create a new JPanel inside my `ActionListener` along with a `HashMap`. I loop through the `HashMap`
adding `String` names and `JRadioButton`and i try to populate the window but i don't really know how.

Here's the piece of code i'm working with:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == theView.viewButton) {

            System.out.println("View Button clicked");
            theView.setBotTextArea("");
            theView.setBotTextArea("Viewing...");

            JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();

            // Method that gather folder names and stores it in an array
            theModel.listAllFolders(); 
            // Make the categories array and store the names
            ArrayList<String> categories = theModel.getListOfCategories();

            // Create a hashmap with names and JRadioButtons
            HashMap<String, JRadioButton> buttonMap = new HashMap<String, JRadioButton>();

            // loop to fill up the HashMap
            for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++ ) { 

                buttonMap.put(categories.get(i), new JRadioButton(categories.get(i)));

            }

            for (Entry<String, JRadioButton> entry : buttonMap.entrySet()) { 

                // Not sure how to retrieve the hashmap data to create and
                   fill up the window

            }
}
```

I'm extremly new to HashMaps (i'm trying to learn it) so i'm not even sure if it's a good idea to begin with. I've been stuck on this task for almost 3 days. In the past i tried to use arrays to accomplish similar task, but i'm almost certain that it's a massive logic error on my part that prevents me from completing it.

I'd appreciate any fresh insight on this matter.

Comment: Why `ArrayList -> HashMap -> JRadioButton`?  Why not the more simple `ArrayList -> JRadioButton`? Or if you need to create a HashMap, then why not one for loop that does both -- that creates the JRaidoButton, that fills the HashMap, that puts the JRradioButtons into a ButtonGroup, and that places the JRadioButtons onto a JPanel (and what confuses you about adding JRadioButtons to a JPanel?)?

Comment: My logic was that i might have issues assigning right names in to right `JRadioButton` in the future. `HashMap` seemed like the best option to prevent that from happening.  I might be over complicating it for myself though. Edit: Would you mind showing me piece of code with your edit? That's pretty much what i've been aiming to do.

Comment: You may be over-complicating it for us. Again, please give us more detail. I'm sure for instance, that you know how to add JRadioButtons to a JPanel, right? Simply call `myPanel.add(myRadioButton)`, so I'm not sure what confuses you about placing your JRadioButtons into the JPanel.

Comment: I might have worded it poorly. I absolutely have no issue adding them at all. I had a problem before since i couldn't acess the JPanel part via controller from the view class. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text shown in the JRadioButton is the same as that placed into the HashMap, I don't see the need for the HashMap. Just make sure that you set your JRadioButton's actionCommand String with the proper text, add all your JRadioButtons to the same single ButtonGroup, and when you want the selection, get the actionCommand from the ButtonModel returned from the ButtonGroup's getSelection() method.

e.g.

```
for (String text : fileList) {
   JRadioButton btn = new JRadioButton(text);
   btn.setActionCommand(text); // radiobuttons don't do this by default
   buttonGroup.add(btn);  // ButtonGroup to allow single selection only
   myRadioPanel.add(btn); // JPanel usually uses a GridLayout
}
// if myRadioPanel is already in the GUI, then revalidate and repaint it
```

later to get selection (if done via another button's ActionListener:

```
ButtonModel model = buttonGroup.getSelection();
if (model != null) {
   selectedText = model.getActionCommand();
}
```

Or if using an ActionListener added to the radio button, then simply get the ActionEvent's actionCommand property.

As for adding JRadioButtons to a JPanel, I am quite sure that you already know how to do this. If a particular step confuses you, you've not told it to us yet.

Comment: Both yours and @ControlAltDel answers helped me tremendously. I got the most important part of it done and it's working very well. Thank you.

Comment: It came down to me not knowing exactly how to make use of the array and fill up the window with JRadioButtons with the correct names and variables. I realised i was making it much more complicated than it really was.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<String> categories = theModel.getListOfCategories();
for (String val : categories) {
  JRadioButton jb = new JRadioButton(val);
  radioPanel.add(jb);
}
//now you need to add the radioPanel JPanel to an existing Container, or call setContentPane(radioPanel);
```